# Drill down navigation + BottomNavigationView.setupWithNavController

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview, drilldown

I have an Android app that uses the navigation component, the app offers a multi-level drill down navigation mode (the hierarchy is dynamic, so there can be an arbitrary amount of levels). I am trying to put that navigation in a tab in a `BottomNavigationView` (and also adding others with the same navigation structure).

I setup the navigation view using `binding.bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(this.navHostFragment.navController)`. The `BottomNavigationView` uses the following menu

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/fragment_1"
        android:title="@string/title_1" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/fragment_2"
        android:title="@string/title_2" />
</menu>
```

`fragment_1` and `fragment_2` are define in the navigation xml among other fragments that can be pushed into the navigation hierarchy. And both are defined as top level fragments using `AppBarConfiguration`.

The app launches fine, and the bottom tabs contain the expected content, but once I start navigating to other fragments (drill down), the current tab loses the current selection (because the id of the new fragment doesn't match the one set in the menu?), if I am on the second one the first one is selected in the bar but the content doesn't change.

What's the proper way of doing this? Is there any official approach? Do I need two `NavHostFragment` and swap them manually when the user changes from one of the bottom tabs to another one?